# Timepart Constraint Issue with 00:30:00 (12:30am)

Tags: sas

GM I have a need to identify timeframes however I am having an issue with 12:30am (00:30:00)

The timestamp shows as 18:00:01

Below is the code being used. If I separate each out, the 6pm constraint it works as expected. However when evaluating 18:00:01 for < 00:30:00, it's not doing what I need. Thoughts on how to get this statement to work?

```
timepart(submit_time) >='18:00:00't and timepart(submit_time) < '00:30:00't then '6pm-12:30am'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is always going to be false.  A single value cannot be both larger than 18 hours and smaller than half an hour.

Use OR instead of AND.

Comment: ah yes, thank you.